# How to start WMP 12 Play all music?

Tags: music, windows-media-player, playback

If you pin Windows Media Player 12 to the taskbar in Windows 7, and right-click on it, there is a option: Play all music 
[image: Play all music]

But I don't want to right click and select it, I want to create a shortcut and pin it to taskbar, when I click it, it opens WMP and automatically "Play all music"
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" /prefetch:11 /Query:3;3;6;Play all music;29518;-1;;;;0;;;;2;;
```

If you have a 32 Bit Windows, remove the ' (x86)' from the path.

How did I know this? I didn't. I fired up [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), then clicked the 'Play all music' from the Windows Media Player context menu on the task bar. Over in Process Explorer I looked at the properties for 'wmplayer.exe' and on the 'Image' tab it shows the full command.

So I have no idea what it all means, but it works (at least on my machine).

Comment: thank you for your help, actually before I asked I opened process explorer to see what the command line is, but :LOL:, i looked at the command line and see "C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" /prefetch:1", I thought that's it, because I didn't use the mouse and move across the box =))